# Importing SQL view vs table

Tags: import, sql, databases

I am trying to import a SQL view not a table in Mathematica.
The command:

```
SQLSelect[conn, "DataByYear"]
```

This will correctly bring in the table.
However using the view name

```
SQLSelect[conn, "QBDateByYear_vw"]
```

Gives an error

> JDBC::error: Invalid object name 'dbo.QBDataByYear'. >>

How do I specify this correctly?

Comment: Does `SQLExecute[conn, "select * from QBDateByYear_vw"]` work?

Comment: Yes that brings in the data in the view.  Now I have to figure out why the WHERE statement isn't working.

Comment: If you are comfortable with SQL, I would recommend using `SQLExecute` for all querying -- the other commands are useful but they can end up doing strange things depending on which database you are using.

Answer (score 3):

In the question you do not specify which database driver you use to open the connection with JDBC. I have been experimenting with Microsoft Access Database drive and I had [similar problems in the past](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/71923).

In that case you **must** enclose the table parameter of type view in your `SQLExecute` or `SQLSelect` query with square brackets, e.g.

```
SQLExecute[conn, "select * from [vwTx-BNAM]"]
```

or

```
SQLSelect[conn, "[vwTx-BNAM]"]
```

Typical cases of table/view that need square brackets around the name identifier are those with spaces, dashes and underscores.

Comment: I don't think that this is the OPs problem as his identifiers don't need any quoting. Nevertheless you probably should mention that square brackets for "delimited identifiers" is a specific feature for MS-Access and MS-SQLServer. I think the "standard" is double quotes but there are other characters in use, e.g. mysql seems to use backquotes as a default.

Answer (score 2):

You may use [`SQLTable`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SQLTable.html) in [`SQLSelect`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SQLSelect.html) so that the table names are properly formatted for the database system you are using.

```
SQLSelect[conn, SQLTable["QBDateByYear_vw"]]
```

You may also find [`SQLColumn`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SQLColumn.html) of interest.

Hope this helps.